# Pandas/Python - Merging files on different columns based on incoming files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python program which receive incoming files. Incoming files are files based on different countries. Sample files are below -
File 1 (USA) -

```
country   state  city      population
USA       IL     Chicago   2000000
USA       TX     Dallas    1000000
USA       CO     Denver    5000000
```

File 2 (Non USA) -

```
country   state  city      population
UK              London     2000000
UK              Bristol    1000000
UK              Glasgow    5000000
```

Then I have a mapping file which needs to be merged with incoming files. Mapping file look like this

```
Country  state     Continent
UK                 Europe
Egypt              Africa
USA      TX        North America
USA      IL        North America
USA      CO        North America
```

Now the requirement is that I need to join the incoming file with mapping file based on state column if its a USA file and join based on Country Column if its a Non USA file. For example -
If its a USA file -

```
result_file = pd.merge(input_file, mapping_file, on="state", how="left")
```

If its a non USA file -

```
result_file = pd.merge(input_file, mapping_file, on="country", how="left")
```

How can I place a condition which can identify the incoming file and do the merging of file accordingly?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, empty the state column for non-US files.

```
input_file.loc[input_file.country!='US', 'state'] = ''
```

Then, merge on two columns:

```
result_file = pd.merge(input_file, mapping_file, on=["country", "state"], how="left")
```

Comment: I can not have condition based on file name as file name will not be consistant

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a unified code for the both two cases, After reading the files, add another column for both DataFrame of fileX (df) and DataFrame of the mapping file (dfmap) with the name of (country_state) in which country and state are combined, then make this column is the linked relation.

for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('fileX.txt') # assumed for fileX
dfmap = pd.read_csv('mapping_file.txt') # assumed for mapping file

df.fillna('') # to replace Nan values with ''

if 'state' in df.columns:
   df['country_state'] = df['country'] + df['state']
else:
   df['country_state'] = df['country']

dfmap['country_state'] = dfmap['country'] + dfmap['state']

result_file = pd.merge(df, dfmap, on="country_state", how="left")
```

Then you can drop the columns you do not need

Adding a modification in which adding `state` if not exist, and set relation based on `country` and `state` without adding the column 'country_sate' shown in the previous code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file1.txt')
dfmap = pd.read_csv('file_map.txt')

df.fillna('')
if 'state' not in df.columns:
   df['state']=''

result_file = pd.merge(df, dfmap, on=["country", "state"], how="left")
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought on this approach but problem in applying this approach in this situation is that Incoming file for non USA countries will have the states but mapping file will not have the state values for non USA countries

Comment: If the file has no 'state' column, add empty one and apply this approach.

Comment: Incoming file has states values for non USA countries but mapping file do not have it

Comment: Check the modification in the answer.

Comment: notice. I used `df.fillna('') # to replace Nan values with ''` for Non(s)

Comment: There's no need in creating a new column. Pandas is able to merge on two columns, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

- -How are you loading the files?
- Are there any pattern in the names of the files which you can work on?

If they are in the same folder, you can recognize the file with

```
import os   
list_of_files=os.listdir('my_directory/')
```

or you could do a simple search in the Country column looking for USA, and then apply the merges according to the situation

Comment: Name of the file will not help as USA files will have the name of the US state while other countries have country name. Then There is going to be a file which will have multiple countries in same file.